# Using active BPF to convert a square wave into a sine

Tags: power, power-electronics, inverter, active-filter, band-pass

I have an inverter that converts 24 V DC to a 48 VAC peak-to-peak square wave with a frequency of 55 Hz. I am then going to use a step-up transformer to output 120 VAC to power some rocket valves that take maximum 150 VA.

We are not sure which ones we are using yet, but I want to provide 150 VA to make sure.
[image: Valves Specifications]

My approach was to use an active wide band pass filter to convert the square wave into a sine wave. The schematic has a first order high pass filter, a non-inverting amplifier that controls the gain, and a low pass filter.

I set the HPF's cutoff frequency to be 50 Hz (\$f_o = 1/(2*\pi*R*C) \$ for a first order filter) and the LPF to be 60 Hz. I also set the gain to be 1 by setting \$ R_4 = 1M\$ and \$R_3=100 \$.

[image: Active Band Pass Filter]
What is wrong in this setup? Why is the output sine not a perfect wave? And if this op-amp cannot provide the inrush current needed, what circuit is capable of preserving power while converting this square into a sine?

[image: Simulation]

Comment: With 1 opamp, configure it as a 3rd order LPF (no need for HPF at all). First order filter is just far too poor at rejecting higher harmonics for your needs.

Comment: @BrianDrummond What is the transfer function for this?

Comment: There isn't a unique one ... search "3rd order Chebyshev LPF" should get something appropriate : simulate it. If it still isn't good enough, Andy's right you may need more, so try 5th, 7th, 9th  order until you find one that is. Or, modify a Cauer filter so the notch (or notches) are aligned with 3rd,5th harmonics.

Comment: @BrianDrummond it looks like he's going from a raised square wave; if he wants a sine wave with zero DC content he'll need a DC blocker.

Comment: The op has also said he needs to drive a load of 150 VA and his previous question on this is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480463/converting-a-square-wave-into-a-sine-wave

Comment: For 150VA he'd be better running that low power sinewave into a PWM generator.

Comment: In your other question you say you need this sine wave to power "some valves on a rocket that need 120 VAC". Exactly what are these valves and why do they need 120VAC?

Comment: @BrianDrummond May you elaborate? What is running this sine into a PWM going to achieve?

Comment: If you want a 150VA sinewave, without PWM you'll be wasting a lot of power. Of course you probably don't need a sinewave, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using an active wide band pass filter to convert a square wave
>   into a sine wave.

For a start, using a band pass filter is wasting circuitry because, in order to convert a square to a sinewave, you need to remove higher order harmonics  above the fundamental frequency and that can be more effectively done with two cascaded low pass filters.

Secondly, if you want anything like a decent shape to the sinewave you’d be looking at a minimum of 4 cascaded low pass filters. On one application I had (where I just couldn’t tolerate any amplitude change across a range of squarewaves between 500 Hz and 700 Hz), I used a 12th order filter To get me about a 32 dB reduction in the third harmonic.

So decide what 3rd harmonic level you can tolerate and design the order of the filter to provide the attenuation needed to reduce that 3rd harmonic.

Comment: I need an active filter because my load needs a certain amount of energy.

Comment: My answer doesn’t explicitly rule out that the implementation is active. An active filter uses (normally) an amplifier in order to improve two 1st order cascaded filters and this would be a natural progression from my direct words but, take note, the circuit in your question is not an active filter; it’s two first order filters with an opamp buffer in between. What power load are you talking about?

Comment: Rocket Valves that take 150 VA. Essentially I created an inverter circuit that outputs a 55 Hz square wave. I want to turn this into a sine wave.

Comment: How pure a sine wave? (e.g. what 3rd harmonic level is acceptable?)

Comment: @Hector you won’t achieve that this way. You need inductor capacitor filters and you need to design them very carefully or you’ll just get smoke and flames. I see that this question is really a follow up to one of your previous questions and the problem with this new question is that you give no indication what your load is and you steer answerers down the path of assuming that you are dealing with signals rather than a big grunt of power. You will not get standard active filters to do this job.

Comment: @Andyaka why can't I use an opamp with a 5 A rating and 10 A peak? I already managed to turn the square into a sine using a 3rd order active Chebyshev low pass filter. I am putting this on a 48 V square wave output

Comment: Because the power efficiency will be about 50% hence, to deliver 150 watts will require something like 300 watts of input power from the power supply. Maybe a tad less, maybe a tad more. The power wasted will be in heat directly from the opamp. Can you afford this loss? Can you afford the heat sink and cooling mechanism?

Comment: @Andyaka What sort of filter do you think is capable of handling such a load? I apologize for not specifying earlier. You mentioned inductors and capacitors, but do you mean an LC ladder?

Comment: Yes I mean an LC low pass filter that may require 2 or 3 stages that *could* be called a ladder.